# Extract values from the loop and add it to the graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, charts, chartist.js

Hello I would like to convert several rectangles graphs where I am taking datas from title and convert it with chartist.js to donut graph. I was thinking to do this with for loop through all ct-chart(its a day) and init the chartist on every day and push the data there but the problem is that when I initialize the graph the data are taken one by one so basically in the first donut graph is only first data so Support3L (E) without AnnualLeave (E) which is in the second day. I am trying to have Support3L(E) and AnnualLeave (E) in first ct-chart graph and Training (E) and Work(E) in second.

I think the problem is in

```
 for (i = 0; i < $graphContainer.length; i++) {
    graphValue[i] = $graphsE.eq(i).width(),
    graphClass[i] = $graphsE.eq(i).attr('class');
 ...
```

but I dont know how to take all graphsE data and add it to one graphValue or is it something else ?

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/767ndb9s/11/

html:

```
<div title="13. 6." class="WorkDayInnerDivEven ct-chart">
    <div title="Support3L (M)
8:00 - 16:00 (8h)" class="Event_Support3L work-day-graph" style="left: 40%; width: 30%; display: none;">
    </div>

    <div title="AnnualLeave (M)
9:00 - 17:00 (8h)" class="Event_AnnualLeave work-day-graph" style="left: 43.75%; width: 30%; display: none;">
    </div>

    <div title="Support3L (E)
8:00 - 16:00 (8h)" class="Event_Support3L work-day-graph" style="left: 40%; width: 30%; top: 85%; display: none;">
    </div>

    <div title="AnnualLeave (E)
9:00 - 17:00 (8h)" class="Event_AnnualLeave work-day-graph" style="left: 43.75%; width: 30%; top: 35%; display: none;">
    </div>
</div>

<div title="14.6" class="WorkDayInnerDivEven ct-chart">
    <div title="Training (M)
3:00 - 8:00 (5h)" class="Event_Training work-day-graph" style="left: 21.25%; width: 18.75%; display: none;">
    </div>

    <div title="Overtime (M)
8:00 - 16:00 (8h)" class="Event_Overtime work-day-graph" style="left: 40%; width: 30%; display: none;">
    </div>

    <div title="Work (M)
17:00 - 23:00 (6h)" class="Event_Work work-day-graph" style="left: 73.75%; width: 22.5%; display: none;">
    </div>

    <div title="Training (E)
3:00 - 8:00 (5h)" class="Event_Training work-day-graph" style="left: 21.25%; width: 18.75%; top: 35%; display: none;">
    </div>

    <div title="Overtime (E)
8:00 - 16:00 (8h)" class="Event_Overtime work-day-graph" style="left: 40%; width: 30%; top: 35%; display: none;">
    </div>

    <div title="Work (E)
17:00 - 23:00 (6h)" class="Event_Work work-day-graph" style="left: 73.75%; width: 22.5%; top: 35%; display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var circlesLayout = function() {

    var $graphContainer = $('.ct-chart'),
        //only the graph with (E) in title is used for donut graph not          overtime
        $graphsE = $graphContainer.find('.work-day-graph[title~="(E)"]').not('.work-day-graph[title~="Overtime"]'),
        graphValue = [$graphsE],
        graphClass = [];

    //hide desktop rectangle-graph
    $('.ct-chart div.work-day-graph').hide();

    //add class circles (its for css)
    $('html').addClass('circles');

    //init chartist
    for (i = 0; i < $graphContainer.length; i++) {
        graphValue[i] = $graphsE.eq(i).width(),
        graphClass[i] = $graphsE.eq(i).attr('class');

        new Chartist.Pie($graphContainer[i], {
            series: [{
                value: graphValue[i],
                className: graphClass[i]
            }]
        }, {
            donut: true,
            donutWidth: 10,
            donutSolid: true,
            startAngle: 270,
            showLabel: false
        });
    }
}
circlesLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have 4 events where title contains (E), two of them have to be graphed on first chart and the other two on the second graph.

You need to modify the `for` statement where you think the problem is, the goal is populate an array of data before you initialize the chartist plugin, I did some modifications:

```
// Array of events
var events = []
events[0] = ['Support3L', 'AnnualLeave']
events[1] = ['Training', 'Work']

//init chartist
for (i = 0; i < $graphContainer.length; i++) {
  var series = [];

    for(j=0; j< $graphsE.length; j++){
    // fill series with the data you want to graph
    // in this case filter Support3L(E) and AnnualLeave (E) for the first
    // Training (E) and Work(E) for the second
    if(events[i].some(evt=>$graphsE.eq(j).attr('class').includes(evt)))
        series[j] = {
            value: $graphsE.eq(j).width(),
            className: $graphsE.eq(j).attr('class'),
            label: j
        };
  }

    new Chartist.Pie($graphContainer[i], {
        // Set data to graph
        series: series
    }, {
        donut: true,
        donutWidth: 10,
        donutSolid: true,
        startAngle: 270,
        showLabel: false
    });
}
```

Those changes already are on your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybrajim/767ndb9s/12/)

Comment: First of all thanks for answer.
Yes you are right but I have several ct-chart (30 and the data are dynamic so I cannot declare them statically) I used 2 only for demo so is it better to use then also loop to push data to events ? or whats the best way ? 

also how can I rewrite '.some()' ?

Comment: I agree that data could be dynamic, but if you want to make a graph with grouped data, then you need to find some pattern to do it, maybe adding other classes e.g.:`group1`, `group2` to your elements, if you want to change the data of a graph that has already been drawn, then you have the [update](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html#chartistbase-function-update) method. To override jQuery functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=override%20jQuery%20function) are some Q/A